# Any risk using SSD w/ SATA controller w/o TRIM (SATA CMD 06 fails)

Tags: ssd, sata

All,
I have found an incompatibility between my SSDs and my PC, I see

```
atax.00 status: { DRDY ERR }
atax.00 error: { ABRT }
```

whenever I try to mkfs.ext4 on these drives. If I attempt to create a RAID partition using these, then the system totally locks up.

That said, after days of frustration I finally found that I can create a file system using mkfs.ext4 -E nodiscard and this works - on top of these partitions I'm then able to successfully create a RAID array.

I'm okay with the performance impact - hdparm and some dd tests show that read/write performance are acceptable for my needs. That said, I'm concerned that by disabling TRIM (which is what I believe I'm doing) there could be some other issue at play here. I can confirm that SMART diagnostics show the disks are fine, and the same behavior is seen w/ 4 SSDs and 3 of the same models of PC - so I'm confident this is a low-level SATA issue and not a defective unit.

Any thoughts on whether or not this lack of TRIM compatibility and/or my use of -E nodiscard to get things working is just burying a problem that will come back and haunt me down the road, or will I merely need to live with a performance hit?
Thanks in advance.

Details: 
I'm using Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64).

I have not seen issues with creating/deleting large files (e.g. dd creation of 8GB file, then rm), or sync, but fstrim did cause a lockup.

Comment: Lack of TRIM isn't a problem, but system lockups are obviously bad... does it also happen when you create a 1G file, sync, delete, fstrim? Is it really related to discard at all? Creating RAID partitions doesn't discard afaia so that should work. Your kernel version?

Comment: Had a similar problem some years ago and it turned out that the disk and the SATA controller somehow were not really compatible and I had to "downgrade" the SATA speed by one generation using the `libata.force=3.0` kernel append. Not sure about the correct syntax...